# React and React-Dom versions should match?

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, package.json, react-dom

Do React and React-Dom have to be the same version?

Example in our app:

React v 15.0.2,
React-Dom v 15.3.1

Everything has been working fine in our app until recently, we are getting a strange error.

`Type Error: Cannot read property 'getNativeNode' of null (ReactReconciler)`

Answer (score 8):

For versions lesser equal than 15.4 they should match.

After release on Nov 16 2016 they have finally separated React and React DOM.

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/11/16/react-v15.4.0.html

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it should be the same version. If not, you will get this error:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

And when you get this error, you can update the version of `react-dom` with this command:

```
npm i react-dom
```